# How to block user - spammer in Smooch

Tags: smooch

I am using Smooch to integrate Whatsapp and Facebook with my API.

Is there a way to block some users on Smooch side so that my API doesn't get any messages from them anymore or should I do it on my backend side?

In the [docs](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/?javascript#schema) there is mentioned a `blocked` flag for `Client Schema`

so it might suggest it could be doable on the Smooch side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `blocked` flag on a client indicates that the user has blocked communication from the business (attempts to send a message to a blocked client will result in a delivery error).

There is currently no way for the business to block communication from a user on Smooch's side, so you'd have to implement that logic yourself